# Paste a link and get thumbnails

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, facebook, social-networking

I want to add a function to my PHP/mysql/jQuery website.
The function is that if user paste a link in a input box,
the server will retrieve all representative pics
just as facebook does.
Is there any PHP code project or jQuery plugin satisfying my demand?

Comment: Why don't you just write it yourself from the scratch? It is not difficult to do.

Comment: Are you looking for a screenshot, or the relevant pictures at the destination?  Screenshots aren't something I'd suggest due to their complexity (although there are a couple of really good services for this).  Relevant pictures is only hard because you have to determine which picture is the most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of services.
Take a look at [websnaper](http://www.websnapr.com/) for example:

[image: websnapr example]

or just [google it](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=thumbnail+service)

It is not hard to write your own from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)  - it retrieves the page and then looks for special meta tags that describe the images associated with that page (`og:image`).

I guess you can write a basic HTML parser that would do the same.

EDIT: Someone has already written an [Open Graph parser](http://buzzword.org.uk/2010/opengraph/#php)

Comment: og:image will override, but for those links which do not contain this metainformation, Facebook will parse the page and has an algorithm to  figure out which picture is relevant (it doesn't just take the first <img> tag).

Comment: How about video?If I paste a youtube or other video host link, how can I show the video part only?